# How can I point from a page a.html to another page b.html

Tags: html

How can I point from a page `a.html`

To a specific div

```
<div id="profs">

...

</div>
```

In another page `b.html`?

I tried

```
<a href ="b.html#profs"> link </a>
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the anchor tag in `a.html`:

```
<a name="profs"> ... </a>
```